# IPtables ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: iptables

I am new to Linux, I used to use windows for years and this is my first time to use Linux "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"

I am hosting a game-server I was wondering if it is possible to make IPtables to kick if 2+ players logged in the my tcp/udp port "7171" in the same second
or block them for 5 seconds I don't need them to be blocked for a long time like the "drop-reject" normal options.

Can someone point me to the right commands or tutorials to make that? Just kick if 2+ players logged in from the same IP to my tcp/udp port "7171" in the same second? or drop/block them for 5 seconds or less thn that?

Thanks in advance
I appreciate anyone's answer/help

Comment: I only know how to do it if the block period (what you want to be 5 seconds) and the 2+ players log in window (what you want to be 1 second) are the same. Would you be interested in such an answer?

Comment: Yeah would be good till I find other option. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: I want when 2+ players log in the same second they get blocked for 1 second only or kicked without block if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that somewhere earlier in your iptables rule set there is:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

as a by-pass once a connection has already been made.
Then the detect and temporary DROP rules are (I have done 3 seconds):

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m recent --update --hitcount 2 --seconds 3 --name BADGUY_GAME -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7171 -m recent --set --name BADGUY_GAME -j ACCEPT
```

Where:

```
eth0 is your external I/F. Change to your actual external I/F name
XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW  is your external IP address. Change to actual.
```

Comment: I know where to put t he first 3 rules but how can I do that one? IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables
EXTIF="eth1"           <<< Change to your actual external I/F name
EXTIP="XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW"  <<<< Your External IP
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that will kick them after log in? after 3 seconds? and where to put the last part? sorry first  time to use linux.

Comment: I had assumed you would need to merge what I gave you with an existing iptables rule set. I'll revise my answer to be an independent script on its own. It shouldn't kick them after login, that is what the bypass is for.

Comment: K thanks a lot I really appreciate your answer, I will try it soon but my dedicated-host went down/off, I think I did something wrong I will call my host providers.

Comment: iptables v1.4.21: unknown option "--dport"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Comment: I must have made a mistake converting from what I normally use, which is TCP only. It'll be awhile, but I'll look into it. You sure you need both tcp and udp?

Comment: Just make one for tcp only, I am sorry for your time and thanks for your interest.

Comment: Yeah that TCP one works great but hey "Someone is hosting the same game-server on Ubuntu 14.04 he made an IPtables script it lets all the character spammers log in then it mass kick them all" Like if he log in 2+ character they log in normally to the game-server then after a while "some seconds" all the characters gets kicked then if he logged in back it wait again for some seconds then "all the characters gets kicked after some seconds" is it possible for you to make a IPtables rule does that?

Comment: From your description, I do not understand how the bad people are identified verses the good people, so no I wouldn't know how to make suggested iptables rules.

Comment: I am sorry for my bad language, I mean something like "2+ logged in at the same second from the same IP are allowed" but then after "a time (some seconds)" they all get kicked, that what exactly he did. they all r getting kicked at the same time.

Comment: "Bad people have to log in 2+ characters at the same second" "good people can log in 2+ characters but in separated time like between each character 20 mints"

Comment: If it is possible to chat? or move that thread to chat? I don't got enough reputation.

Comment: I do not recall how to go into chat. I do not think I know how to do what you want anyhow.